# Add parameter values to an existing tag in XML

Tags: xml, shell, awk, sed

I am trying different ways to add new values to an existing tag in my XML file.

My original XML:

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
      connectionTimeout="20000"
      redirectPort="8443"/>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

I want it to transform into:

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
      connectionTimeout="20000"
      redirectPort="8443"
      scheme="https"
      secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
      keyAlias="tomcat" keyPass="welcome"
      keystoreFile="/data/matrix/automated-setup/openam.jks"
      keystorePass="welcome" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

I don't want to use XSLT here. How can I do it using sed or awk?
It has to be added under  tag only

Comment: Using xml parser in linux will add overhead of command. it has to be generic set of commands like sed or awk.

Comment: So is there any general rule on where the lines must be added, under `Catalina` or after `redirectPort` etc? Include more specifics

Comment: It has to be added under <Connector> tag only. adding after redirect make look better to see whats extra parms are added

Comment: does every connector tab always end with "redirectPort......"?? and after this line you want to add the extra lines?

Comment: My apologies..I meant does every Connector port tab end with "</Service>" and before this line you want to add the extra lines?

Comment: There are multiple connector port tag under one service tag. I want to add parameters only to "<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" />.

Answer (score 2):

A sed script like this would work

```
sed  '
/^[ ]*<Connector port=.*protocol=.*/,/[ ]*<\/Service>/ {
\#.*"/>$# {
s#\(.*"\)/>#\1\n      scheme="https"\n      keyAlias="tomcat" keyPass="welcome"\n      keystoreFile="/data/matrix/automated-setup/openam.jks"\n      keystorePass="welcome" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>#g 
}
}' $1
```

where you call the script with the name of the file after it.

if you want to change the following information

```
  scheme="https"
  secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
  keyAlias="tomcat" keyPass="welcome"
  keystoreFile="/data/matrix/automated-setup/openam.jks"
  keystorePass="welcome" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

operate on this section of the script

```
\n      scheme="https"\n      keyAlias="tomcat" keyPass="welcome"\n      keystoreFile="/data/matrix/automated-setup/openam.jks"\n      keystorePass="welcome" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>#g
```

**results given from this script**

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
      connectionTimeout="20000"
      redirectPort="8443"
      scheme="https"
      keyAlias="tomcat" keyPass="welcome"
      keystoreFile="/data/matrix/automated-setup/openam.jks"
      keystorePass="welcome" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Comment: This is not working for me . Something is wrong in here.

Comment: I made command slightly change to handle my space issues at end of tags. It worked for me.

Comment: When i tried with orginal file of apache tomcat i.e server.xml , it is not able to replace.

Comment: have you tried "sed -i.bak......" which will back up file with a .bak extension and make the actual changes?

Comment: Yes. No luck. If you have apace tomacat setup, in conf there is server.xml . with that file there is some tab or space issues so its not working properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it with sed or awk, one way is

```
awk '{ print }
 /<Connector / {
   print "      scheme=\"https\""
   print "      secure=\"true\""
   print "      SSLEnabled=\"true\""
   print "      keyAlias=\"tomcat\" keyPass=\"welcome\""
   print "      keystoreFile=\"/data/matrix/automated-setup/openam.jks\""
   print "      keystorePass=\"welcome\" clientAuth=\"false\" sslProtocol=\"TLS\""
 }' foo.xml
```

This inserts the parameters directly under a line that contains `<Connector`. **However**, this approach is very brittle. If the XML file contains, for example, a line

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

(that is, if the tag is closed in the same line), then it will yield unexpected results. There are ways to deal with individual such problems, but dealing with all what-could-possibly-go-wrong cases in sed or awk is going to be difficult, in part because you'd have to figure out first what all the cases are. Imagine how it would look if you had to expect all of

```
<Connector/>
<Connector />
<Connector><someothertag/></Connector>
<ConnectorProperties foo="bar"/>
```

...and, honestly, you do have to expect them. I **strongly** advise you to use tools that are meant to deal with XML rather than raw text.  Modifying XML files with sed or awk is, in my view, foolhardy.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have to expect multiple connector tags and dealing with them is tedious for me. I am avoiding using XML tools since if the script runs on customer environment, it adds overhead to add the required tool for customer. If you know any generic tool that will be available by default on CnetOS kind of machine suggest me. 

Let me know if i can able to handle multiple <Connector tags>

Comment: I don't work with CentOS, so I don't know what's in their default repo. Check if they have xmlstarlet, then you could do `xmlstarlet ed -a //Connector -t attr -n foo -v bar` to add an attribute `foo="bar"` to the `Connector` tag. Instead of `//Connector`, you can use any XPath.

Comment: The overhead of an XML parser is pretty trivial by current software size standards. The days when we were trying to keep applets under 10K (not 10M) are, alas, long gone. Also, it's not unlikely your customer already has an XML parser available; Java ships with a version of Xerces, for example, though last I checked it was backlevel and had some annoying bugs.